# MapActivity android studio

Tags: android

I have problem in my program. I implements https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start this, and have problem on my code.

my build gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

// Google play services

implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
```

In ma code i don't have access to my res file and don't know how to resolve this, and

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .build();


PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
        placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
```

And GEO_DATA_API, PLACE_DETECTION_API, GeoDataApi don't work when i update build griadle and for this     implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

Try th following

Initialize below code inside Oncreate();

```
// Add an import statement for the client library.
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places;

// Initialize Places.
Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "***YOUR API KEY***");
// Create a new Places client instance. PlacesClient placesClient = 
Places.createClient(this);
```

New PlacesAPI is initialised..

For AutoComplete places use below code (You can use AutoComplete Fragment also)

```
// Set the fields to specify which types of place data to return.
List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME);
// Start the autocomplete intent.
Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
    AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields)
    .build(this);
startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
        Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
    } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
        Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // The user canceled the operation.
    }
  }
}
```